# Why is 'mutable' a lambda function attribute, instead of being a capture type?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does c++11 require us to write:

```
[a,b]() mutable { a=7; } // b is needlessly mutable, potential source of bugs
```

Instead of:

```
[mutable a,b]() { a=7; } // no problems here
```

Is this an oversight, considered not important enough, or is there a specific technical reason?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a mention about your suggestion in [n2651](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2651.pdf):

> The syntax for lambda expressions could be extended to allow declaring
> whether the closure members should be declared mutable or not.
>
> **This approach could be confusing to programmers, as the mutability is not a
> property of the closure object, but rather the variables stored in the
> closure.**

I don't know if this is the only reason, but it does seem like it was considered.
However, in [Herb Sutter's proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3424.pdf), he suggests getting rid of `mutable` and not making the capture copies implicitly `const`, so we might see changes again.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  I'm happy to know it was at least considered, even if I do not think I agree.  Also, I like Herb's proposal, esp. if you add the ability to mark captures as const (which is a missing feature for capture-by-reference atm).

Comment: After reading the full section in the linked paper, I'm not sure I buy the argument at all (I mean moreso than just not agree, I don't understand the logic).  The claim is that since mutability is a property on the variables stored in the closure, and not of the closure itself, that it would be confusing to qualify the variables and we should instead the operator, thus effectively changing the mutability of the whole closure.  Generally confused by this argument about potential confusion ;)

Comment: @mmocny: I'm not 100 percent sure about the logic either, but when `mutable` is applied to the entire object, you know that you may get different results on subsequent calls. When this is applied only to member variables, it is not as clear as to the mutability of the closure object.

Comment: @JesseGood fair argument (and I know that you are just interpreting): "the mutability of the whole closure changes as soon as any member is made mutable".  However, lambda capture-by-reference already affects "mutability" (in that subsequent calls may return different values) yet doesn't require the keyword.  Same for capturing pointers by value, etc.  No matter what, programmers must be aware of which/how each variable is captured.

Comment: @mmocny: I agree that this is not a strong argument. However, note that with capture-by-reference, the closure object is considered to have **no state**, as the state is stored outside the closure. `mutable` is property representing the state of the closure, so it is not needed when there is no state.

Answer (score 6):

Probably an oversight (in the same way as rvalue refs can't be used) of sorts and an artifact of the way lambdas are conceptually implemented.

```
int   a;
int*  b;
float c;

auto lambda1 = [&a, b, c](int d) mutable -> void {};

class lambda1 {
public:
    void operator()(int d) {}
private:
    int&  a_;
    int*  b_;
    float c_;
};

auto lambda2 = [&a, b, c](int d) -> void {};

class lambda2 {
public:
    void operator()(int d) const {}
private:
    int&  a_;
    int*  b_;
    float c_;
};
```

Comment: lambda2 would have int* const b_; and const float c_; right? EDIT: nevermind, I see that the op() function is const qualified, which makes sense now.

Answer (score 5):

The `mutable` keyword applies to the object generated by the lambda expression and not to individually captured items so that it can be implemented by the compiler using a `const` modifier on the `operator()` method as described in section 5.1.2, paragraph 5 of the standard.

> This function call operator is declared const (9.3.1) if and only if
>   the lambdaexpression’s parameter-declaration-clause is not followed by
>   mutable.

In your example, the class generated by the lambda expression could look like this:

```
class lambda
{
  int a, b;

public:

  lambda( int a, int b ) : a( a ), b( b ) {}

  void operator()() // non-const due to mutable keyword
  {
    a = 7;
  }
};
```

Comment: He knows what `mutable` does, he's asking why the syntax is the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `mutable` keyword isn't used like the `mutable` keyword is normally used: It is meant to be the opposite of `const` in this case and applies to the constness of the function call operator the implicit function object. However, it was intentional that the function call operator of the implicit function object is `const` by default while normally member functions are non-`const` ("mutable") but default. The introduction of lambda functions predated the use of contextual keywords (`override` and `final`) and the `mutable` keyword seemed to be a better choices than `not const`.

Comment: He's asking why he can't mark individual members as mutable for use in the const function body, rather than remove the const function altogether.